# How to make http://qilayout.com/ like header effect?

Tags: jquery

I wanna know they made their logo .. i think... that's jQuery but i want to play fade effect like that in Css and html . with Opacity =D. So.. if anyone know... tell me how to ?
Thanks

Comment: superuser is for computer hardware and software related questions **only**. Programming questions should go to stackoverflow, website design questions should be asked on doctype.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the sides sourcecode? 
I just did, with Firefox and found this in the first line:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
            jQuery("div#slider1").codaSlider()
            // jQuery("div#slider2").codaSlider()
            // etc, etc. Beware of cross-linking difficulties if using multiple sliders on one page.
```

Well, I don´t really know anything about coding webpages (except for basic html :-D) but I hope this helps.
The code is commented as far as i saw.

Answer (score 0):

They have a graphic as a background image to a span that is positioned over it. They then animate the opacity of that element.